# VMware Fusion Ubuntu is stuck on black screen and can't load anything

Tags: unix, virtualization, vmware

I am using VMware Fusion to open up an Ubuntu VM on my Mac. The screen currently just shows up as a black screen and doesn't load anything. I have access to VMware Preferences but can't access the actual computer in the VM.

I tried rebooting the VM and it did not work. I looked around at the settings but couldn't find anything to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Which specific Mac model and macOS are you using?

Comment: I am using an Apple M1 Pro with Ventura 13.1

Comment: You’ve verified that you’re using VMware and Ubuntu for Apple Silicon?

Comment: Yes, the VM has worked in the past but has not been working after restarting it.

Comment: It may have crashed. Try a clean install of Ubuntu in a new VM

Comment: I tried creating a new VM and it was working. However, when I had to reboot it during the setup, it crashed again.

Comment: It seems to be a VMware/Ubuntu issue.  I don’t think it’s an Apple issue

Comment: Where can I get help with this problem? I asked originally on Stack Overflow but was redirected to here and Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: VMware has a forum for asking questions like that.